# How to disable automatic timezone adjustments in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, datetime

I'm attempting to resolve a problem in angular 1.4.5 involving dates and automated timezone adjustments

I'm using .NET to pass DateTime data (1/1/1990 for example)

When angular renders this, timezone adjustments are applied and will render the date to the UI as 12/31/1989

How do I stop angular from behaving this way?

The data being passed are a person's Date of Birth, timezone is irrelevant, the date I pass in should remain exactly the same, this undesired behavior is causing huge problems in our system.

Comment: Send the dates with timezone information.  Every date you send from the server should be either in UTC or the users timezone.

Comment: This is probably javascript/client machine related and not angular. I'm pretty sure you'd be ok using timestamps

Comment: The problem is absolutely client side. How do I disable this behavior via angular? If I pass a specific DateTime to angular, I don't want angular assuming I mean DateTime+ 5hours or -10 hours or whatever.